# Mac OS X Key Remapping

Tags: macos, process, keyboard-layout, remapping

I'm trying to remap CapsLock to Control Programmatically.

I figured out the edits that need to be done to a plist file (.GlobalPreferences.[MAC ADDRESS].plist)

The point is that changes I make to that file apply only after logging in/out, while if I change it through the preference pane it applies immediately.

Clearly there is some process/service that needs to be restarted/notified.

But how can I figure out which one it is? Do you know or have some idea on how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing something which would be considered unsupported at best. There is no acceptable means of notifying the operating system that you've modified one of its preferences files behind its back and there probably never will be.

What you *can* do is either make the change through AppleScript, write your own CGEventTap or live with restarting.

Comment: specifically upvoted for the suggestion to use AppleScript.